# Apart from using 'with', what else can I do to have the same results?

Tags: python

The code:

```
with open("integers.txt", "r") as fin, \
       open("products.txt", "w") as fout:
```

The answers should be put in another file.

Comment: What do you mean "Apart from using 'with'"? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Apart from using 'with', what else can I do to have the same results?*

```
with open("integers.txt", "r") as fin, open("products.txt", "w") as fout:
```

You can replace this `with`/`as` block with two variables:

```
fin = open("integers.txt", "r")
fout = open("products.txt", "w")
```

Then you only have to remember to write

```
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

at the end of your program.

---

I would suggest you to read the documentation about [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) and [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)/[`as`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0343/) blocks.

---

What's more I don't get why you are doing this:

```
def mult(a, b=1, c=1, d=1, e=1, f=1, g=1):
     return a * b * c * d * e * f * g
```

This function can only have 7 arguments, why don't you use [`*args`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/args-and-kwargs)?